# php: Fix doubly encoded UTF-8 string

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

(There seem to be many similar questions how to fix these strings in MySQL or in other languages, but none for PHP)

I have a double-encoded UTF-8 string, for example:

```
Ã¼ber
```

which should be

```
über
```

How to fix it with PHP?

Comment: Find & Replace using str_replace function.

Comment: This may seem simple but the answer may be too complex and we do not have enough information to diagnose it correctly. In short: reverse whatever misencoding you applied, if that operation is actually reversible. See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) for a primer on encodings so you can diagnose it yourself.

Comment: @Jack You're going to do this for all 100.000+ possible Unicode code points?

Comment: @deceze: Nope. If it's 5-6 then we can use